# How to get the height of the Tkinter Text widget after resizing?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to get the height of the Tkinter Text widget after resizing? How to get a new height in the number of rows?

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.viewText = tk.Text(parent, height=32, width=20)
        self.viewText.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tk.Tk()
    window = MainWindow(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Which do you want, the height in pixels or the height in lines? Also, when do you want to get this? Whenever it changes, or when called from some function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `<Configure>` event. For example:

```
import tkinter.font as tkfont

def on_configure(ev):
    """Get the current font and convert the pixel size into character sizes"""
    font = tkfont.nametofont(ev.widget.cget("font"))
    width = int(ev.width / font.measure("0"))
    height = int(ev.height / font.metrics('linespace'))
    print("{0}x{1}".format(width, height))

text.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)
```

Comment: And how to get a new height in the number of rows?

Comment: You find the text metrics for the currently defined font and convert the pixel values to character counts.

Comment: Be aware that the height may not be 100% accurate since you can use multiple font sizes in a text widget.